# Suppressing file not found errors when using jquery ajax .load()

Tags: jquery

Bit of a long shot here. I'm loading pages from another domain to display fragments of the page on a separate domain. Problem is the remote domain pages contain a load of images with absolute pathing EG:

```
/assets/images/something.jpg
```

I'm parsing these after the load has completed to correct the page, but console still reports loads of broken images, presumably from when the ajax first runs. Is there anyway of suppressing these errors please?

He's an example of my loading code:

```
$('#myDiv').load('http://www.myDomian.com/myPage.aspx #mainContent', function(){
   $('#myDiv').html($('#myDiv').html().replace(/\/assets\/images\//g, "http://www.myDomain.com/assets/images");
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) so you can intercept the data in the response and modify it prior to its injection into the DOM:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.myDomian.com/myPage.aspx'
}).done(function( data ) {
    var
        $myDiv = $('#myDiv'),
        modifiedData = $(data).find('#mainContent')[0].outerHTML;

    modifiedData = modifiedData.replace(/\/assets\/images\//g, 'http://www.mydomain.com/assets/images');

    $myDiv.html(modifiedData);
});
```

Comment: This is getting close but the URL doesn't like http://www.myDomian.com/myPage.aspx#mainContent. It says not found. It works with just http://www.myDomian.com/myPage.aspx, but I then end up with the whole page. I've tried filtering in the .done() function but I can't get it to work. How can I filter out just the #mainContent of the page please?

Comment: I don't get it. This should work, but I'm getting an "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression" now being thrown in console, and it then just lists the whole page?

Comment: @user1001421 I've fixed my edit. Please check it out and try again.

Comment: Sorry, still the same. I've commented out all the stuff in the done function. console.log(data) is fine and displays the loaded page. But console.log($(data).find()) throws the "unrecognized expression" error. So does console.log($(data).find('#mainContent')) and console.log($(data).find('#mainContent')[0].outerHTML).

Comment: @user1001421 [Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SeGyr/) you can play with. The sample code in my answer assumes your response type is either `text/html` or `text/plain` based on the string manipulation you're doing.

Comment: Thanks André. Must be something to do with my data. I'll have a play. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading them into a detached element first, then fixing the links, then attaching the element to the DOM.

For example:

```
var newDiv = $('<div></div>');
newDiv.load('http://www.myDomian.com/myPage.aspx #mainContent', function(){
   $('#myDiv').html(newDiv.html().replace(/\/assets\/images\//g, "http://www.myDomain.com/assets/images");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still generates the errors in console. Thanks for the response.